# IBMQ: `from qiskit import QISKitError` gives 'cannot import name QISKitError'

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

When I run:

```
from qiskit import QISKitError
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QISKitError'
```

I need QISKitError for exception handling with my program. Did IBMQ recently update this import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been moved to `from qiskit.exceptions import QiskitError`